# Flutter Custom Multi Selection

Tags: flutter

#### Question

Hi, how can I implement a custom multi selection widget in flutter? Here is an example :

[image]

I have a list of widget created with a ListView.builder and I simply want to change color based on userTap.

How can I implement this? I'm able to change color when user tap on one option but then, when another button is tapped I can't understand how to reverse the state of the old selected option.

I was searching for a solution with flutter standard state management or maybe with bloc library.

#### example code

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: SelectableContainer(text: 'option', index: index,),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SelectableContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final int index;

  SelectableContainer({
    @required this.text,
    @required this.index
  });
  @override
  _SelectableContainerState createState() => _SelectableContainerState();
}

class _SelectableContainerState extends State<SelectableContainer> {
  bool _isSelected = false;
  Color unselectedColor = Colors.white;
  Color selectedColor = Colors.blue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        setState(() {
          _isSelected = true;
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        height: 50,
        color: _isSelected ? selectedColor : unselectedColor,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(widget.text),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share some boilerplate code which you have so far.

Comment: I've updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `setState` method, you can just do `_isSelected = !_isSelected;` instead of always setting it to true. That way the tile will get unselected if `_isSelected` is set to true.

Although the above way wil solve your problem, there is also another widget flutter has for this same scenario called `ListTile`. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) is a link to the documentation. You might also want to check that out. It also has an `onTap` callback built into it directly.

Here is a quick app I built using `ListTile`. Hope it solves your problem. Cheers!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DemoClass extends StatefulWidget {
  _DemoClassState createState() => _DemoClassState();
}

class _DemoClassState extends State<DemoClass> {
  int _selectedIndex = -1;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            height: 50,
            color: _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('This is some title'),
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              }),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: DemoClass(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: You solution isn’t exactly what I’m looking for. Doing this, only another user tap will deselect the option. I need a selection widget where only one option is selected at any given time. I was searching for a way to communicate to the old selected option to deselect

Comment: That's exactly why I have recommended the `ListTile` widget. It also has a boolean `selected` property which will achieve what you want. Please check the link I have provided in the answer. It also contains sample code and all other explanation.

Comment: I saw the documentation and the fact that there is a selected option don’t help me with my problem. That option only emulate your solution to use _isSelected = !_isSelected. Maybe my question wasn’t clear, I’m struggling with English.

Comment: I just added code for a sample app I created using `ListTile`. Please run it directly on your device. I think it is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: With this method I lose the possibility to animate the transition I think

Comment: Updated my answer. Remove the `selected` property of the `ListTile` and wrap the `ListTile` inside an `AnimatedContainer` and set the `color` depending on the condition `_selectedIndex == index`, just like you were doing for the `ListTile`.

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please accept it by clicking on the checkbox.

Comment: You were helpful but, as I said to the other guy, this solution is extremely inefficient cause it forces the reload of the entire list view. This could be quite heavy

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. It's a question and answer forum. You won't get the golden solution which satisfies each and every one of your criterias. But you will definitely get pointed in the right direction. The solution I posted does force the reload of the entire list on calling `setState()`, but it can be circumvented easily with callback functions or other state management techniques.

Answer (score 1):

First store the selection in list when the user select an item

```
selectionList.add(title.id);
```

Then in the ListView.builder change the color of the title if it's in the selectionList

```
Title(color: selectionList.contain(listOfTitls[index].id)? Colors.green : Colors.White);
```

**update**
this trick will do it for you

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        setState(() {
          _isSelected =_isSelected? false:true;//this line
        });
      },
```

Comment: I think that this solution will force me to rebuild the entire list every time, and in this way i also lose the possibility to animate the transition

Comment: I think if you do this method with a provider it will not rebuild the entire page but im not sure.

Comment: Using Provider will not change the situation. In order to change color Option Widget need to rebuild. I’m detaching for a solution to rebuild only the interested option and not the entire list